# How to view entire messages in the notification drawer?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

I've received some security notifications, but I can't seem to figure out how to view the entire thing. See the huge image below:

[image: Screenshot]

They do not scroll, I cannot pinch-zoom or drag them to reveal more information, and when I tap one it disappears. Is there a log of these somewhere? I can use ADB if I have to, but surely there's a way...

Comment: Have you tried pinch-zooming them open?

Comment: Ah, no I haven't but I'm not aware that any notifications use that. Regardless, I will try it the next time they show up.

Comment: Another option that works for many notifications is to drag them downward to expand. Email, SMS, and other notifications support this - no idea if these will though.

Comment: @Nick For example Gmail, K-9 Mail and Spotify use pinchable notifications to show more details about received messages and playing tracks.

Comment: @onik, Yes I just got a new gmail and tried it. Will keep that in mind the next time it shows up.

Comment: @onik, a notification came up again; I tried pinching/dragging down without results. Looks like I need to look into any logs.

Answer (score 2):

Just pull down the notification(not the notification bar, the specific notification you want to expand) with two fingers to expand(if and only if,the notification supports expanding).

if you cant expand it with two fingers swiping down, then just turn on the auto rotation and navigate to somewhere (which can be rotated, in my case I use to go to settings) and then slide down your notification bar. It should be visible by now.

:)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I never realised I could pull down on the actual notification. This tip changed my life :heard: